# How to use pivot to add more columns across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called employees. That houses employee information. However, I also have tables called phone_types, phone_manager, email_types, and email_manager.

Phone_types has the following columns, phone_type_id, phone_type_name.

Phone_manager has the following: phone_id, employee_id, phone_number, phone_number_extension, phone_type, date_added, deleted.

Email is very similar.

What I'm trying to do is grab all the pertinent information for all employees into a single view, so basically everything from the employees table, and all their phone numbers and emails, all on a single row, for every employee. How would I go about doing this? Keeping in mind that employees can literally have near infinite phones. (We have one employee with 6).

Comment: Can you limit the maximum number to display in the single view?  For example, no more than 10 phones?  Otherwise, you would need some sort of Dynamic SQL solution to generate the column list, which is doable but complicated.

Comment: I was thinking of only doing 3 total phones, home, work, mobile, and using the filed date_added to display the newest numbers. Those 3 are fulfilled by the values of phone_type 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a view that joins your employees to phone type, phone manager and email with all the output columns you want to see.   Then use excel to pivot row data to cols.  Here is one of many examples on how to do this:

http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/

An alternative is to create a pivot query:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)